# How to edit DB file and insert multiple records in one of its table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I've been working on some of my projects, and I am feeling stuck because my software takes 1 or 2 hours to load those 10,000 records (basically it goes through lengthy way and I want to skip it).

Luckily I know that the software uses .db file to save fetched records and I am sure that if I can put my custom list in table of .db file, it will show up in software without need to go through lengthy process. I used some .db viewer and editor and through those tools, i was able to see my desired table (in which there are records), and there was "Insert record" option too, but imagine that I want to put 10,000 records and inserting record one by one is way huge time consuming.

Therefore, I want to edit one table of that .db file and insert custom records (multiple) in one or few clicks rather than 10,000 clicks.

.db file is located in AppData > Roaming ... etc

Is there any way to achieve? For your information, I use Windows 7 operating system.

Comment: Is this MySQL or MSSQL? Or is this something like sqllite?

Comment: What is the "lengthy way", by hand, one at a time?   Depending on the DB, you could create an insert script. 10k records would not take long to insert.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your interest. I was able to insert multiple records through Insert SQL query and now everything is working perfectly.

Thanks!